# Problemas para referenciar elementos del dom. Tambien duda con el each

Tags: jquery

```
                                        <td class="product-name">
                                            <a href="single-product.html">Juan ramon ibañez</a> 
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-price">
                                            <span class="amount">600.40 €</span> 
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-quantity">
                                            <div class="quantity buttons_added">

                                                <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text cantidax" title="Qty" value="2" min="0" step="1" > 

                                                <a href="" class="btn btn-warning actualizaCantidad" ><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-subtotal">
                                            <span class="amount"></span> 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                    <tr class="cart_item">
                                        <td class="product-remove">
                                            <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="qtviOQDNvRIOVAO0RFUKF4UKfWs9LGrKHpScuzKR">
                                            <input type="submit" value="x" title="Eliminar este elemento" class="remove" > 
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                            <form method="POST" action="c" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="qtviOQDNvRIOVAO0RFUKF4UKfWs9LGrKHpScuzKR">
                                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="single-product.html"><img width="145" height="145" alt="poster_1_up" class="shop_thumbnail" src="/ima/1.jpg"></a>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-name">
                                            <a href="single-product.html">Manuel Bernal Garcia</a> 
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-price">
                                            <span class="amount">200.20 €</span> 
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-quantity">
                                            <div class="quantity buttons_added">

                                                <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text cantidax" title="Qty" value="1" min="0" step="1" > 

                                                <a href="" class="btn btn-warning actualizaCantidad"  ><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-subtotal">
                                            <span class="amount"></span> 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

```
   <tr>
                                        <td class="actions" colspan="6">

                                            <input type="submit" value="Actualiza Importes" name="update_cart" class="button actualiza_importe_compra" >
                                            <input type="submit" value="Pagar" name="proceed" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

La idea es la siguiente, este es el codigo fuente final de un proyecto que estoy haciendo.
He puesto solo dos filas ya que el codigo es dinamico, y es una repeticion del tr con la clase cart_item.

Lo que quiero es que cuando pulse en el boton con la clase .actualiza_importe_compra sume todos los totales de cada fila, pero al utilizar un input number para modificar la cantidad me esta fallando, es por ello que para hallar el total de totales, tendria que encontrar todos los precios multiplicarlos por la cantidad de cada fila e ir sumandolos(acumulandolos). El problema lo tengo a la hora de referenciar cada precio y cada cantidad usando el each, que por cierto no lo he usado mucho

```
    $('.actualiza_importe_compra').click(function()

     {  

            var inputCantidad = parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('input.cantidax'));
            var precio = parseFloat($(this).parents('tr').find('.product-price.amount'));
            $.each(function(index,value)
            {
                var total = inputCantidad.val() * precio.text();

                    console.log(total);
            });

            return false;

 });

        });
```

Esto es lo que tengo pero no me funciona, tengo problemas para referenciar al pulsar el boton la cantidad y el precio dinamicos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que con este ejemplo podrias tener una idea de como implementarlo

[[ASP.NET] - GridView sumar columnas con jquery](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2012/05/aspnet-gridview-sumar-columnas-con.html)

veras que para recorrer la tabla y sumar una columan usarias

```
var total = 0;
$('#TablaId tr:not(:last)').each(function() {

    var coltotal = parseFloat($("td:eq(3) span", this).html());

    if (!isNaN(coltotal)) {
        total += coltotal;
    }

});
```

en este caso como tenia un footer en la tabla use el `:not(:last)` pero sino es tu caso puedes quitarlo, la idea es iterar cada `tr` con el `td:eq(3)` seleccionas la tercer columna, en este caso contenia un span, pero peudes cambiar esto por [:text](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

Comment: Hola, he probado a hacerlo a tu manera y despues de darle muuuchas y muuchas vueltas al final lo he conseguido, a sido un poco mas sencillo que como yo lo usaba ya que mi metodo iba desde el boton subiendo o bajando a la etiqueta que hiciese falta. Tu sistema se basa en buscar de arriba a abajo tomando como referencia el inicio de la tabla y no el boton. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: claro la idea es ir iterando cada row partiendo desde la tabla, me alegra que haya sido de utilidad para resolver el problema